# Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt_bind_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

My hosting company doesn't provide MySQLnd so I had to change some things on my code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "SQL statement failed";
} else{
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ...
```

When I change `$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);` to `$result = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt);` it gives me

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt_bind_result()
```

and

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
```

I have been working on this for two days and I couldn't solve it because I beginner. What should I do?

Comment: Check what `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` would be expecting - it should have a list of the columns you want to retrieve.

Comment: If you don't know what columns will come out (using `*`), you will need to dynamically create an empty array and bind the values to it with keynames from `result_metadata` and `fetch_field` in a loop, prior to doing `bind_result` in a `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: Or, you can switch it to PDO ;) much easier.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I'm sorry but I couldn't understand a thing that's too complicated for me as a beginner. :\

Comment: @NigelRen 
if (empty($name)|| empty($desc)) {
     echo "Empty name or description.";
    }
    else{
     $sql= "SELECT * FROM table1; ";
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      echo "SQL statement failed!";
     }
     else{
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $incase = $rowCount + 1;

Did you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear with me on this, as its been ages since I've used procedural mysqli...

If you wish to dynamically bind the column params and do a fetch loop (because mysqlnd is not an option), then this code here achieves that.

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// now before you loop on $stmt->fetch, you must bind all the columns that exist
// to a row which will hold the values during the looping on fetch (yes, confusing)

$row    = array();  // will hold each fetch'd loop result
$params = array();  // something to pass keyed references to $row with
$params[] = $stmt;  // add the $stmt object as first param (for procedural way)

$meta = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);// get what those columns will be

while($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    if (!isset($row[ $field->name ])) { $row[ $field->name ] = null; } // set if not set
    $params[] = &$row[ $field->name ]; // add reference to keyed row value
}

$meta->close();// metadata no longer needed, close it

call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_result', $params);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    // in here you then have $row to use as before
    echo $row['id'];

}
```

Now, you may be thinking I went overkill here... yes. That example is for dealing with *unknown* sql column grabs (using the `SELECT *` syntax). However if you know all columns coming out, you can simply bind each one before the while loop like this:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $col2, $col3);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    // in here you then use $id, $col2, $col3
    echo $id;

}
```

This is why switching to the `PDO` library can make things horribly easier, as it has provisions for simply fetching a row with associative keynames in a simple loop like you know and love with `mysqlnd` available. However if `PDO` is also not an option, you are left with painful and arcane ways to deal with "binds" and "mysqli".